# Where can I see the original message from an approved LinkedIn invitation to connect?

Tags: linkedin

I have accepted a few invites from the top navbar button, but then I realised some had possibly useful or interesting messages attached.

How can I retrieve LinkedIn invitation messages in the 2015 redesigned messaging system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select "Message" under the member's intro and their original message will come up in the chatbox. As of 4/2/2019.

The intro message used in the invitation by a new connection to get in touch with your will be listed in the Relationship tab of their profile.

Example of an intro message shown on the profile page:

[image: LinkedIn intro message on the profile page.]

Note: I could not find a way to get the intro messages for rejected connection requests.

Comment: No, invitation message will not be in relationship tab. I have accepted few of invitations and I can not see that "I would like to add ..." message in relationship tab. If user has send a message then it will show in relationship tab.

Comment: You have to click "See More" in order for the initial contact message to appear

Comment: This was a stupid stupid product decision. Some people actually use this opportunity to say something relevant, but 99% keep the default *I'd like to add you to my professional network on LinkedIn* without touching it. It's a pity that the true messages get obfuscated together with irrelevant noise.

Comment: There is no relationship tab any more, and the initial message does not show up in the Messaging tab.

Answer (score 1):

Now this facility is not available.

From [Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61013):

> The ability to **Archive a Message** will no longer be available. Any messages that were previously archived will appear in your message list.
>
> To view previously archived messages:
>
> 1. Click the **Messaging** icon at the top of your homepage.
> 2. Scroll through the list on the left rail until you locate the previously archived message and select it.

Comment: See _Mikolaj Kmita's_ reply on [this thread](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/389676/retrieving-an-accepted-invitation-to-connect.html).

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you please tell me why downvote?